# Increment memory value

Tags: memory, increment, registerhotkey

Consider a processor that supports the following instructions :

```
AND/OR/XOR/ADD/SUB A, B
NOT A
```

where A is a memory location or a register and B is a register. No
immediate operands are supported.

Write a set of instructions to increment a memory location M without
assuming any existing values in registers or memory locations.

Comment: It looks like a homework to me. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your starting point:

```
XOR REG, REG
```

I leave the rest of the homework as an exercise.